# How to retrieve profile URL with Facebook SDK in android studio?

Tags: android, facebook, url, sdk, profile

In android studio how to retrieve the user's profile URL with facebook SDK like this one

https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100003728482385

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All those old ways of linking to the user profile using the user id or app-scoped user id won’t work any more.

You need to ask for the `user_link` permission, and then you can request the `link` field from the user object. This will return a URL with a token, that can be used to link to the user’s profile. (The token likely limits the time for how long this link can be used, so you should not store it for long-time use, but request a “fresh” one when it is needed.)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_link
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user